# Does private mode enable "Do Not Track" (DNT) on popular browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, safari, http-headers

I have found quite a lot of requests in my web server logs coming from various browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) with [Do-Not-Track header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track) enabled.

I suspect that these users have not enabled Do-Not-Track manually because it is not a popular and widely known user setting, in my opinion, but rather that it's being enabled for them when they use each browser's "private mode".

**So does "private mode" actually enable Do-Not-Track? on popular browsers**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I quickly tried whether private browsing turns on DNT (i.e., includes a `DNT: 1` header) when "do not track" was not already enabled in the preferences.

- Firefox 39 (Android): no
- Firefox 41: no
- Chrome 43 (Android): no
- Chrome 45: no
- Opera 12.16: no
- Internet Explorer 11: yes
- Safari 6/7 (Mavericks): yes (according to [docs](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17168?locale=en_US))
- Safari 8 (Yosemite): yes (according to [docs](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19216?locale=en_US))
- Safari 9 (Yosemite): yes (tested by OP, on Safari 9.0 (10601.1.56.2))
- Safari (iOS): yes (implied by [docs](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203036))

Comment: What about Safari 9 & Safari mobile? Can you please test Edge and Opera too?

Comment: I've now included some more results. I don't have Microsoft Edge installed, though.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Christoph! You have the bounty. :)